# sqlite3 doesn't show results

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm having problems with a search in a sqlite3's file, I have a database with columns below:
Title,artist,lyrics,tracking

My code is the is that:

```
def search(title,artist,query):
 if title and artist and query:
  db = sqlite3.connect('songs.db')
  cursor = db.cursor()
  cursor.execute('SELECT ? FROM song WHERE title=? and artist=?',(query,title,artist))
  result = cursor.fetchall()

  if result:
     print result
  else:
     return False
```

I have set text_factory to str, but it fix another problem that I had, I have checked the database with a viewer like sqliteman, and tried to search through terminal and it works well. ¿Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: if you build the query as a string, without using paramerized query, is it the correct query?

Comment: I tried it now and seems that it works when the variable "query" is removed and I put lyrics. The statements that works is like thats:
cursor.execute('SELECT lyrics FROM song WHERE title=? and artist=?',(title,artist))

Comment: weird, never considered that the select columns aren't allowed to be parameterized

Comment: Finally I limited my program to two queries, lyrics and tracking. I think that when I use ? to pass a value it is passed like 'lyrics' and not just like lyrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters in SQL queries are always replaced as fixed values.
In other words, strings are always replaced as strings, not as column names.

To customize column names in your query, you must not use SQL parameters but do the replacement in Python:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT %s FROM song WHERE title = ? AND artist = ?' % (query),
               (title, artist))
```